# How do you declare a vector inside of a constructor of a container class?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, constructor, containers

I am trying to declare a `vector` in the constructor of a container class. The vector should be empty to start, I will use `.push_back()` in the `main.cpp` to add to it. Do I even need to set it to something in the constructor?

```
class Collection{
    private:
        vector<Card> setOfCards;
        int numCards;
        int maxSpend;
    public:
        Collection(int numCards, int maxSpend){
            this->numCards;
            this->maxSpend;
            setOfCards = new vector<Card>();
        }
```

Comment: Short answer: no. A vector will be initialized to empty by default, so if that's what you want, you don't need to do anything in the ctor to get it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) If code is vital to your question, post it in the question. Not an image, not a link, not a link to an image, but the actual text. 2) A `vector` and a `vector*` are not the same thing.

Comment: You can't use `push_back` elsewhere in the code to add to a vector inside of a class unless you break encapsulation. That sentence raised a red flag.

Comment: I suggest to read a book in the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4123703) since you have numbers of errors in this snippet.

Comment: In C++, members (and variables) are default initialized (using the default constructor, unless specified otherwise). This means you **should not** use `new`. The vector will be created with the object instance, and will be empty by default. You can simply start using `setOfCards` as soon as `Collection` is created without needing anything special.

Newcomers to C++ should never need to use `new`, unless you understand what it entails.

Comment: In  the constructor, unless you have explicitly initialised `setOfCards` differently,  it WILL have size of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your class contains a member `vector<Card>` object, but `new vector<Card>` returns a `vector*` pointer to an object.  You can't assign a `vector*` pointer to a `vector` object.

Nor do you need to.  `vector` implements a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), so your `setOfCards` member will be constructed automatically when the compiler enters your constructor.

That being said, your constructor is ignoring its input parameters.  The statements `this->numCards;` and `this->maxSpend;` are no-op's.

The code should look more like this instead:

```
class Collection{
    private:
        vector<Card> setOfCards;
        int numCards;
        int maxSpend;
    public:
        Collection(int numCards, int maxSpend){
            // setOfCards has already been constructed by this point!
            this->numCards = numCards;
            this->maxSpend = maxSpend;
        }
```

Or, using a *member initialization list*:

```
class Collection{
    private:
        vector<Card> setOfCards;
        int numCards;
        int maxSpend;
    public:
        Collection(int numCards, int maxSpend) :
            /* setOfCards() is called implicitly here, */
            numCards(numCards),
            maxSpend(maxSpend)
        {
            // setOfCards has been constructed by this point!
        }
```

See [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) for more details.